# Как выравнить по центру select html5

Tags: html, html5, select

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/f9copdtm/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="select">
     <select>   
        <option value="-1">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
        <option value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
        <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
        <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
      </select>
   </div>
    <div class="select select2">
     <select>   
        <option value="-1">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
        <option value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
        <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
        <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
      </select>
   </div>
    <div class="select select3">
     <select>   
        <option value="-1">Выбрать</option>
        <option value="Чебурашка">Чебурашка</option>
        <option value="Крокодил Гена">Крокодил Гена</option>
        <option value="Шапокляк">Шапокляк</option>
        <option value="Крыса Лариса">Крыса Лариса</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper{    
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
.select{
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px auto;    
}
.select select{
    width: 150px;       
}
.select2{width: 100px;}
.select2 select{width: 100px;}

.select3{width: 70px;}
.select3 select{width: 70px;}
```